# How to create tags when creating time series in Apache IoTDB inegrating with c#?

Tags: c#, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I did not see any tags when integrating Apache IoTDB in c# API to create a time series. If I need to use this tag function, how can I get access to it? Can it only be created through SQL statements? If so, how should I write this SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session in Java has the method to add tags for time series in Apache IoTDB, so you can check that. If you can only use C#, see if you can execute methods like `session.executeNonQuery` to execute sql statement to add tags.